# Communicating with a backend from frontend in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

My problem is that I have seprate services for both the back and front ends when I go into a pod and run the curl http://backend it resolves and communicates with the backend pod but then I put it into my angular as http://backend it tells me it can't be resolved, How is it that the pods can communicate but the running application cant

Comment: Can you specify more details, like your Deployment files and how the services communicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) provides visibility inside the cluster. If you want to expose your Service to the outside world you need to use an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

P.D.: You could expose your services using NodePort but it is not recommended.

P.D. (2): If you already have a Backend Service and a Frontend Service, what makes sense is only to expose the frontend via ingress, and keep backend only reachable inside the cluster, to be consumed only from Frontend

Comment: Okay but the problem I am currently having is that if I run a curl cmd I can communicate with the backend inside the pods cmd line no problem its when angular try to make a HTTP request it's telling me it can't resolve the name http://backend

Comment: Both, Ingress and Service provides load balancing out of the box. The default implementation uses round-robin. You can choose other implementations if you need it.

Comment: Oh okay so its okay if I have 2 loadbalancer services one for frontend and another for the backend?

Comment: If the backend provides an http API to be consumed from the outside world then you need to expose it via Ingress